# How To In Bitbucket Cloud: Always View Pull Requests Side-by-side?

Tags: view, pull-request, bitbucket-cloud

I wanted to in Bitbucket Cloud: Always View Pull Requests Side-by-side.

I was searching on Google with the phrase "Bitbucket Cloud: Always View Pull Requests Side-by-side" and I found no good first hit that would help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got help from a colleague to do it. Inside a pull request: `Settings` (shown boxed in red, below) > `View`:`Side-by-side` > `Save`.

[image: Pull Request: Settings]
[image: View: Side-by-side, Save]